# HTML5 time picker minutes to display only 15 minutes interval data in dropdown

Tags: html, time, timepicker

I am trying to display only 4 lists of dropdown in minutes

1. 00
2. 15
3. 30
4. 45

But could not make through it. I tried to add step, but it only works with key up-down. What I want is to hide it from dropdown as well. Is it possible? Need help. Tried to hide using css but could make it.

PS: I have been using `<input type="time">` for this, no other libraries if possible.

Comment: Are you asking about the `<input type="time">` time picker or one included in another framework/library/package/etc...?

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention that. Yes I was talking about ```<input type="time">```

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of the various `input` types is left to the browser. This is to allow for different standards across operating systems and device types. Unfortunately, it also means that you are at the mercy of the browser vendors to implement support for all options you want to use.

There is a [`step`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#htmlattrdefstep) attribute that can be used to round up to the nearest desired interval, but as the [usage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#using_the_step_attribute) notes,

> This property has some strange effects across browsers, so is not completely reliable.

Ideally, it takes a number of seconds that define the minimum step between intervals. For 15 minutes, that would be 900 seconds.

```html
<input type="time" value="09:00" step="900">
```

This feature appears to be [adopted](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlinputelement_step) in recent updates, but your mileage may vary.

Since the dropdown is browser-specific, I do not know of a way that you can limit the values it shows. If you need that level of control or if you need to target browsers that do not support this attribute, then you will need a custom control.

Alternatively, you could listen for the `input`'s `change` event and round up to the nearest 15 minutes programatically. This is only an example. You will absolutely run into issue with timezones, time formats, and possibly other unforeseen issues.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  let myTimepicker = document.getElementById("my-timepicker");
  myTimepicker.addEventListener("change", function() {
  
    console.log(`User changed the value to ${myTimepicker.value}`);
    
    let [hours, minutes] = myTimepicker.value.split(":");
    
    minutes = (Math.ceil(minutes / 15) * 15);
    if (minutes == 0) minutes = "00";
    if (minutes == 60) { minutes = "00"; ++hours % 24; }
        
    let newValue = hours + ":" + minutes;
    
    console.log(`Rounding value to ${newValue}`);
    
    myTimepicker.value = newValue;
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="my-timepicker">
```